# IF Exists doesn't seem to work for a Table Drop if already exists

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, ddl

Was getting this error each and every time tried to execute a DROP Table if exists

Step 1: Created a Table

```
CREATE TABLE Work_Tables.dbo.Drop_Table_Test (RowID INT IDENTITY(1,1), Data VARCHAR(50))

INSERT INTO Work_Tables.dbo.Drop_Table_Test 
SELECT 'Test' UNION
SELECT 'Test1' UNION
SELECT 'Test2' UNION
SELECT 'Test3'
```

Step 2: Wrote a IF Exists block to check if the Table exists.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Work_Tables.dbo.SysObjects WHERE NAME LIKE  'Drop_Table_Test' AND XType = 'U')
BEGIN
 PRINT 'IN'
 DROP TABLE Work_Tables.dbo.Drop_Table_Test
END

CREATE TABLE Work_Tables.dbo.Drop_Table_Test (RowID INT IDENTITY(1,1), Data VARCHAR(50), NAME VARCHAR(20), PreCheck INT)


INSERT INTO Work_Tables.dbo.Drop_Table_Test (Data, Name, PreCheck)
SELECT 'Test','SRK',1 UNION
SELECT 'Test1','Daya',2 UNION
SELECT 'Test2','Dinesh',3 UNION
SELECT 'Test3','Suresh',4
```

On running the Step 2 Code its obvious the Table has to be Dropped and recreated with the same name but it didn't even enter the Begin End block.
[image]

I feel that its because have added few more columns in the second try, but still not clear why it should have problems as we are to DROP the table.

Comment: The above script seems to work fine after adding `GO` after the 'BEGIN END` statement, but I am still not clear why its not working when GO is not used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You can not drop and create the same table in the same batch in SQL Server**.

Break your code up into separate batches so the table can be dropped before you try and recreate it. Add `GO` after `END` in your `BEGIN / END` statement.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Work_Tables.dbo.SysObjects WHERE NAME LIKE  'Drop_Table_Test' AND XType = 'U')
BEGIN
 PRINT 'IN'
 DROP TABLE Work_Tables.dbo.Drop_Table_Test
END
GO   --Add this...
....
```

Straight from [Microsoft's Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173790.aspx):

> DROP TABLE and CREATE TABLE should not be executed on the same table in the same batch. Otherwise an unexpected error may occur.

Comment: thanks a lot, so in simple terms two DDL statements cannot be executed at the same batch.

Comment: @Joby generally speaking, yes

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use this syntax:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.Drop_Table_Test', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
  DROP TABLE dbo.Drop_Table_Test;
```

`IF EXISTS` will drop the table only when your table `Drop_Table_Test` does not contain any row. In case if it contains the data then it will not drop the table.

Comment: Hi @Rahul Tripathi the `IF EXISTS` does seem to work to Drop the table even if there rows in the table. I feel the reason is something related to the number of columns that are added in the Step 2 part.

`CREATE TABLE Work_Tables.dbo.DropTest (RowID INT IDENTITY(1,1), Data VARCHAR(50))

INSERT INTO Work_Tables.dbo.DropTest 
SELECT 'Test' UNION
SELECT 'Test1' UNION
SELECT 'Test2' 

IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Work_Tables.dbo.SysObjects WHERE NAME LIKE 'DropTest' AND XType = 'U')
BEGIN
 PRINT 'IN'
 DROP TABLE Work_Tables.dbo.DropTest
END
`

Comment: @Joby:- No, Step 2 is not responsible for it. If your table has records in it. Then you cannot drop it using the `IF EXISTS`

Comment: I am actually able to Drop the table even if the table has records in it using `IF EXISTS`, can you please try out a scenario and help me on this.